# Error message 000800 when using Summary Statistics in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arctoolbox, error-000800

I am a new GIS user working in ArcMap and am having a problem with the Summary Statistics tool. I want to calculate the area burned per California County using a new field 'Area_Acres' that I added to attribute table using 'Calculate Geometry'. However, any field that I enter into the Statistics Field creates :

> error message 000800: the value is not a member of sum | mean | min | max | range | STD | count | first | last.

I am not sure if relevant: I was advised to use 'double' for data type when creating the new field but I have also tried long integer, short integer, float and text.

See attached photo.

[image: Sceenshot_Wildfire_Area_Exercise]

Answer (score 1):

Summary statistics options must be specified

[image]